# Resident evil7 black screen

Tags: resident-evil-7

When i click play Re7.exe in goes to black screen and nothing  happen just black screen, can some one help me ?

this my PC :

- **BIOS**: LENOVO BIOS Rev: ESKT23A 0.0
- **Processor**: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3350P CPU @ 3.10GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.1GHz
- **Memory**: 8192MB RAM
- **Card name**: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
- **Dedicated Memory**: 2006 MB

Comment: Is this the Steam version as you're starting from .exe?

Comment: ...or a version obtained from unofficial sources? Try launching via Steam.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the issue is that you don't meet the minimum specs for Resident Evil 7.

Various [sites](http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=8072&game=Resident%20Evil%207) including [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/418370/), list the minimum (Intel) processor as **Intel® Core™ i5-4460**. Despite some sites listing the i5-4460 as 2.7Ghz, [it is a 3.20 GHz processor](https://ark.intel.com/products/80817/Intel-Core-i5-4460-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz).

It is [benchmarked as 7% faster](http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i5-4460-vs-Intel-Core-i5-3350P/2310vsm3018) than your i5-3550P. Your processor is just not powerful enough.

You may still be able to do this if you are familiar with overclocking, at least one [forum](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1716859/overclock-3350p.html) discusses overclocking your CPU.

Comment: Sys Req lists the i5-4460 at 2.7Ghz, while the benchmark lists it at 3.2Ghz. Not to mention, comparing CPU's is not that simple. The instruction set it 99% identical for both processors, so it's extremely unlikely that it is the cause of the black screen. Unfortunately, without more details about the issue, it's impossible to identify the cause...

Comment: @Chippies, although the Steam specs list it as a 2.7Ghz processor, Intel also lists it as 3.2 Ghz.

Comment: The Steam specs don't list the i5-4460 as a 2.7Ghz processor. It list the minimum requirements as a cpu equivalent of i5-4460 at 2.7Ghz.
And even if it was at 3.2Ghz, should we say that any CPU under that frequency doesn't meet the requirements? Even if it *didn't* meet the performance requirements, the game should still at least launch, so there's something else at fault.

Comment: Btw, the minimum requirements on Steam are for 1080p/30fps, which means that anything less than that would be even easier to run.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys for help and answer, already figure out the problem. the reason why my re7 go black screen is my monitor to old for that framerate and resolution, so i try to play in my old laptop and yeah it run even with all lag.